# Mechanize with FakeWeb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I'm using Mechanize to extract the links from the page.
To ease with development, I'm using fakeweb to do superfast response to get less waiting and annoying with every code run.

```
tags_url = "http://website.com/tags/"
FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, tags_url, :body => "tags.txt")

agent = WWW::Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(tags_url)
page.links.each do |link|
   puts link.text.strip
end
```

When I run the above code, it says:

```
nokogiri_test.rb:33: undefined method `links' for #<WWW::Mechanize::File:0x9a886e0> (NoMethodError)
```

After inspecting the class of the page object

```
puts page.class # => File
```

If I don't fake out the tags_url, it works since the page class is now Page

```
puts page.class # => Page
```

So, how can I use the fakeweb with mechanize to return Page instead of File object?

Comment: If you keep your answer acceptance level this low, people will stay away from your questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use FakeWeb to replay a prefetched HTTP request:

```
tags_url = "http://website.com/tags/"
request  = `curl -is #{tags_url}`
FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, tags_url, :response => request)

agent = WWW::Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(tags_url)
page.links.each do |link|
   puts link.text.strip
end
```

Calling curl with the -i flag will include headers in the response.

Comment: Thanks 4 ur reply. But doesn't the above code hits the real site over internet everytime I run it? though curl with option -i return the header, my objective was not to hit the internet every time so I kinda like to use the FakeWeb option.

Comment: no. the code in the backticks shells out and stores the response in `request`. You put the first 3 lines in a `before(:all)` block if you are testing with RSpec, therefore the site would be called once.

Comment: This will hit the url, even if it's once. Felipe's answer is the correct one.

Comment: It's not incorrect. Just load a fake response from a file instead of back ticking curl.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily fix that adding the option `:content_type => "text/html"` you your `FakeWeb.register_uri` call